# Oracle SQL counting the days of the week of the same month

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

How can I count the days of each week for a specific month that the user will give to my SQL query? For example, if the user gives April 2021, the result will be:

[image]

If the user gives May 2021 the result will be:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the query you are looking for:

```sql
SELECT WEEK AS WEEK_NUMBER, COUNT(*) AS WEEK_DAYS
FROM (SELECT TO_CHAR(FIRST_DAY + (LEVEL-1), 'IW') AS WEEK
      FROM (SELECT supplied_date AS FIRST_DAY, LAST_DAY(supplied_date) - SUPPLIED_DATE+1 AS DAYS
            FROM (SELECT TO_DATE('05/2021', 'MM/YYYY') AS SUPPLIED_DATE
                  FROM DUAL))
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= DAYS)
GROUP BY WEEK
ORDER BY WEEK;
```

Just replace the inner TO_DATE with your date.

**Edit 1: Additional Column (See Comments)**

```sql
SELECT MONTH_NAME, WEEK AS WEEK_NUMBER, COUNT(*) AS WEEK_DAYS
FROM (SELECT TO_CHAR(FIRST_DAY, 'MONTH') AS MONTH_NAME, TO_CHAR(FIRST_DAY + (LEVEL-1), 'IW') AS WEEK
      FROM (SELECT supplied_date AS FIRST_DAY, TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(supplied_date), 'DD') AS DAYS
            FROM (SELECT TO_DATE('05/2021', 'MM/YYYY') AS SUPPLIED_DATE
                  FROM DUAL))
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= DAYS)
GROUP BY MONTH_NAME, WEEK
ORDER BY WEEK;
```

Note: I also changed the way I calculate the number of days in the month.

Comment: if i want to add another column with the name of that month (e.g. "May"), how can i do that?

Comment: You can add another TO_CHAR to the middle query. Then in the outer query add that column to the SELECT and GROUP BY

Comment: I'm trying to do this, but I keep getting an error ... can you please show me in the query what to do?

Comment: @Apostolos - Your additional request doesn't make a lot of sense. Since "May 2021" is the input from which all the computation is derived, who or what will need to know this information in the output? It is already known to the caller (whoever that is: a human user, or another process, etc.) before the query is ever called. It is trivial to add to the query output, but *WHY*?

Comment: @Apostolos: Check the edit to my answer.  I also found an easier way to figure out the days in the month.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a direct computation of the same. The input is given as a string, such as `May 2021`; you can use a bind variable in its place. Just keep in mind the possibility that the user may be in a non-English-speaking locale; as long as they use their local language in passing the month to the query, everything should work fine.

```
with
  inputs    (mth) as (select 'May 2021' from dual)
, first_day (dt)  as (select to_date(mth, 'fmMonth yyyy') from inputs)
, mondays (dt, ord, lst) as (
    select  trunc(dt, 'iw') + 7 * (level - 1), level, max(level) over ()
    from    first_day
    connect by level <= 1 + (trunc(add_months(dt, 1), 'iw') - trunc(dt, 'iw')) / 7
  )
select to_number(to_char(dt, 'iw')) as week_number,
       case ord when 1   then dt + 7 - trunc(dt + 7, 'mm')
                when lst then last_day(dt) + 1 - dt
                         else 7 end as week_days
from   mondays
order  by week_number
;

WEEK_NUMBER  WEEK_DAYS
----------- ----------
         17          2
         18          7
         19          7
         20          7
         21          7
         22          1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the weeks (without needing to use any aggregation) using:

```sql
WITH input ( month ) AS (
  SELECT DATE '2021-04-01' FROM DUAL
),
weeks_of_month ( month_start, week_start, end_day ) AS (
  SELECT TRUNC( month, 'MM' ),
         TRUNC( month, 'IW' ),
         LAST_DAY( TRUNC( month ) )
  FROM   input
UNION ALL
  SELECT month_start,
         week_start + INTERVAL '7' DAY,
         end_day
  FROM   weeks_of_month
  WHERE  week_start + INTERVAL '7' DAY <= end_day
)
SELECT TO_CHAR( week_start, 'IW' ) AS iso_week,
       GREATEST( month_start, week_start ) AS first_day_of_week,
       LEAST( end_day, week_start + INTERVAL '6' DAY ) AS last_day_of_week,
       LEAST( end_day + 1, week_start + INTERVAL '7' DAY )
       - GREATEST( month_start, week_start ) AS days
FROM   weeks_of_month;
```

Which outputs (with the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` set to `YYYY-MM-DD (DY)`):

> | ISO_WEEK | FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK | LAST_DAY_OF_WEEK | DAYS |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 13 | 2021-04-01 (THU) | 2021-04-04 (SUN) | 4 |
> | 14 | 2021-04-05 (MON) | 2021-04-11 (SUN) | 7 |
> | 15 | 2021-04-12 (MON) | 2021-04-18 (SUN) | 7 |
> | 16 | 2021-04-19 (MON) | 2021-04-25 (SUN) | 7 |
> | 17 | 2021-04-26 (MON) | 2021-04-30 (FRI) | 5 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6e0c0b3e75d751b5a30309a946cc9da4)*